# Regex not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to return true if a string is 16 characters or more with regex here is what I'm currently working with.

### CODE:

```
"<p>#MichiganHouseWarehouseEvent</p>" == /\S{16,}/
```

I'm trying to say `if string is 16 chars or more without a space return true` but this returns false... Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `\S` matches any non-whitespace char, is that what you need? The `==` is a wrong operator here. It must be `=~`.

Comment: Sorry didn't mention that. I needs to be a word that non-spaced 16 chars or more

Comment: It would probably be a lot safer to use an HTML parser to tackle this problem than some regular expression. What if there's embedded tags in there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A String cannot be equal ([`==`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-3D-3D)) to a Regexp. It can [match](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) one, though.

## Complete string

If you want to check that the complete string has more than 16 characters and none of them is a whitespace (or a newline, or a tab...) :

```
"<p>#MichiganHouseWarehouseEvent</p>" =~ /\A\S{16,}\z/
#=> 0
```

Note that in Ruby, `0` is truthy. It is the index on which the match begins.

With Ruby 2.4, you could use [`match?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-match-3F) to get a boolean directly.

## Substring

If you want to check there's at least one substring with 16 non-whitespace characters :

```
"0123 01234567890abcdef" =~ /\S{16}/
#=> 5
```

This condition is less restrictive than the previous one :

```
"0123 01234567890abcdef" =~ /\A\S{16,}\z/
#=> nil
```

You could also use :

```
"0123 01234567890abcdef".split.any?{ |no_space| no_space.size >= 16 }
#=> true
```

Comment: You can triple-equals it, which like `=~` is somewhat obfuscated, or you can `.match` it.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Totally right. I got my ruby golden badge yesterday BTW. :) Thanks a lot, I learned many things with your feedback and answers!

Comment: Congratulations and thanks for the kind words. I've never seen a Rubiests rocket ahead on SO as you have. Keep it up.